# Zurb Foundation 4 - no paddings for first and last columns

Tags: grid, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 4 and Sass in my project. I'm having trouble with the column's gutter. My problem is that columns have paddings on both left and right side, except if the column spans the full width.

So if I have a row with an element spaning the full width (12 columns), it has no paddings and its width is 100%. But if I have another row with several columns on it, the first and the last ones are indented by the gutter, so they don't align with the element above.

An example:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="widget">
        Some contents here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <aside>Left aside, first column</aside>
    <section>Right section, last column</section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.widget {
    /*Spans the 12 columns*/
    @include grid-column($total-columns); 
}
aside {
    @include grid-column(3);
}
section {
    @include grid-column(9, true);
}
```

So you see, the `widget` will have no paddings and will be larger than the `aside` + the `section`.

I've read in Bootstrap first and last columns don't have paddings on them and I'd like to do something like that. I've tried to use "collapse" on the parent row but it doesn't seem to do anything, the paddings are still there.

I know I can add a `.first-class` to the first column and doing `.first-class { padding-left: 0 !important; }`, that's the most common answer I found, but it doesn't seem very semantic...

I wish Foundation would add a parameter to their grid-column mixin for managing paddings like this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wish Foundation would add a parameter to their grid-column mixin for managing paddings like this!

[`grid-column` already has a `collapse`property](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html). You could also just specify `padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0` yourself, but `collapse` [will do that for you](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/ae8576a755aff351c3af21b13b2ef6627823567b/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss#L70).

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks! I was trying to apply `collapse` to the row not the columns... The explanation about the `collapse` option in Foundation Docs doesn't seem quite clear to me because it says _"If you have a collapsed row, you need to set the columns to collapse as well."_. But my row is not collapsed so I kind of skiped it. I prefer the github source in your answer where it clearly states _"If collapsed, get rid of gutter padding"_. That I understand! :)